# Can not deserialize instance of POJO out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I have json like this

```
[
    {
        "name" : "New York",
        "number" : "732921",
        "center" : {
                "latitude" : 38.895111, 
                "longitude" : -77.036667
            }
    },
    {
        "name" : "San Francisco",
        "number" : "298732",
        "center" : {
                "latitude" : 37.783333, 
                "longitude" : -122.416667
            }
    } ]
```

using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ i generated below pojo classes

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Center.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnyGetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnySetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"latitude",
"longitude"
})
public class Center implements Serializable
{

@JsonProperty("latitude")
private Double latitude;
@JsonProperty("longitude")
private Double longitude;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private final static long serialVersionUID = -7995395877218484665L;

@JsonProperty("latitude")
public Double getLatitude() {
return latitude;
}

@JsonProperty("latitude")
public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
this.latitude = latitude;
}

@JsonProperty("longitude")
public Double getLongitude() {
return longitude;
}

@JsonProperty("longitude")
public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
this.longitude = longitude;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Location.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnyGetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnySetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"name",
"number",
"center"
})
public class Location implements Serializable
{

@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("number")
private String number;
@JsonProperty("center")
private Center center;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private final static long serialVersionUID = 3575741942846550732L;

@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
return name;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty("number")
public String getNumber() {
return number;
}

@JsonProperty("number")
public void setNumber(String number) {
this.number = number;
}

@JsonProperty("center")
public Center getCenter() {
return center;
}

@JsonProperty("center")
public void setCenter(Center center) {
this.center = center;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

when i make a post call from my rest client with same pay load above 
i am getting error

```
Can not deserialize instance of com.example.Location out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@ef77e4a; line: 1, column: 1]
```

my Rest end point looks like this (ResponseObject is my custom response).

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseObject create(final Location Location) {
        ResponseObject responseObject = new ResponseObject();
        responseObject.setStatus("200");
        return responseObject;
    }
```

What am i missing here?
I was looking DeserializationFeature but not sure how to set that Pojo level?

i am not using ObjectReader in this case

any help?

**Update**

By making a List of locations i solved the issue. 
But, if the JSON does not have uniform data like below, I am getting List of Locations each one populated with one object. I mean the first Location is populated with Object containing name,number...and the second Location object is populated with xxx object(the other object is null).
Is there any way to have Single Object binding for below kind of json?

```
[
{
    "name" : "New York",
    "number" : "732921",
    "center" : {
            "latitude" : 38.895111, 
            "longitude" : -77.036667
        }
},
{
    "xxx" : [
        "yyy" : "zzz"
      ]

} ]
```

]

Comment: Your method should look like this `public ResponseObject create(final Location[] locations)` or `public ResponseObject create(final List<Location> locations)`

Comment: Thank you. that worked. this is working fine if the locations are having uniform data. How the POJO Looks like if the JSON does not have uniform data ? JSON format updated in question, the problem here is i can change the JSON, i need to prepare POJO for the input JSON

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an array as input but the Location in a single object.

Comment: Thank you. that worked. this is working fine if the locations are having uniform data. How the POJO Looks like if the JSON does not have uniform data ? JSON format updated in question, the problem here is i can change the JSON, i need to prepare POJO for the input JSON